# Proper acceleration of a stationary object

Tags: reference-frames, acceleration, relativity

What is the proper acceleration measured for a stationary object? is it 9.8 or 0?
Thank you.

Comment: With respect to which reference frame ?

Comment: Hello. If I understand the question correct, you ask whether an object has an acceleration of 9.8 from gravity or zero? If so, then, any acceleration depends on the reference frame. So, do you ask for a specific reference frame? We can say,that at the moment we accelerate as a galaxy moving in space(again in some reference frame).

Comment: It's _proper_ acceleration, which is (to give a simple description) the acceleration in the object's own reference frame. The proper acceleration isn't a frame-dependent quantity because its definition already specifies a frame.

Answer (score 4):

Proper acceleration is acceleration away from following a geodesic. As such, it is $0$ if and only if the object in question is free falling. If there is any net non-gravitational force, then there is proper acceleration.

Standing still on the Earth's surface is *not* free falling. The ground is preventing free fall, and proper acceleration is $g$.

Note that proper acceleration is *not* dependent on frame. It is the acceleration measured by an accelerometer that is being carried by the object in question. The opinions of other accelerometers moving in other ways have no bearing on it.